# Windows Phone variable class type

Tags: windows-phone

I want to create a a user class type object, and then maybe later change its class type. For Eg.

There are two custom class:

```
class A{}
class B{}
```

then later i want to declare a object which changes it's type accordingly;

```
var obj;

if(x=0)
    obj=new A();
else
    obj=new B();
```

is this possible in windows phone visual studio environment?
NOTE: I want obj to be a global variable, so that I can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but not a great design. You should have it more typesafe, either by having a base class for A and B and your variable object as that base type or have the classes interfaced.

Example:

```
class BaseClass
{
}

class A: BaseClass{}
class B: BaseClass{}

BaseClass obj;
```

or

```
interface IClass{}

class A : IClass{}
class B: IClass{}

IClass obj;
```

Comment: ht i understand you used inheritance. thats a solution, but i dnt think i can use it. let me explain my prob further. i am more looking for polymorphism. The same object will behave differently, depending on it's class type.

    class A
    {
       String str="Class A";
    }
    class B
    {
        String str="Class B";
    }


    var obj;
    if(...)
       obj=new A;
    else
       obj=new B;

    obj.str......

Comment: Interface is made for polymorphism. The idea is not to have a generic type of object, rather have a specific type that'll have it's own implementation.

Comment: ok.. thanks a lot.. lets see how can i implement this with my idea.